# tsc with tsconfig does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

My directory has 2 files:  a `tsconfig.json` with simply `{}` and a hello.ts with a line that says `console.log('help!!');`.

When I run `tsc hello` I get the additional `hello.js` as expected.

If I delete `hello.js` and run `tsc` intending to pick up my configuration I get nothing. No error message, no `hello.js`.  I'm sure I'm missing something easy!

NOTE: My hypersimple tsconfig is just for purposes of this discussion. I have tried several options including the simple one created with `tsc --init`. I don't want to include `files` specifically but have `tsc` pick up all the files in my folder [as documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: Have you tried specifing `files: [ "hello.ts" ]` in the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Are you using a Windows computer? If so, what's the output of this command: `where tsc`?

Comment: I think we're going to need more information to figure this one out.  I just set up a project identical to yours and running `tsc` on it's own generated the `hello.js` without problems.  Is this Windows or Mac?  Where is TypeScript installed?  If windows, as the comment above me states, try `where tsc`.  If mac, try `which tsc`.

Comment: thanks for looking.  `where tsc` on my windows 7 machine yields

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.js

Comment: I thought I had it installed globally by npm too so I'll try that.  However, I will still be stumped by why it worked if specifying hello on the command line but not picking it up throught the tsconfig.

Comment: `npm install typescript =g` and running `cmd` as administrator seems to work. I'm blaming my corporate desktop setup and not TypeScript!  thanks for the help.